# Jsp with java codejersey

Tags: java, jsp, jersey

I write simple Jax-Rs app (Restful), and try to return `jsp` file with java code. But, when I run app I get the error:

```
Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: com.sun.jersey.api.view.Viewable of media type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
```

My jsp file:

```
<%@ page import="com.trofimovep.models.Book" %>
<%@ page import="com.trofimovep.dao.BooksDao" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>

<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Bookshop</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    This is a bookshop!
    The books on our site:

            <%
                BooksDao booksDao = new BooksDao();
                ArrayList<Book> books = booksDao.getBooks();

                for (Book book : books) {
                    out.println("<tr>");
                    out.println("<th>" + book.getName() + "</th>");
                    out.println("<th>" + book.getAuthor() + "</th>");
                }
            %>

    <button type="submit">Make order</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

And function:

```
@Path("/bookshop")
public class Start {
    @GET
    @Path("/books")
    @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
    public Response Books() {
        return Response.ok(new Viewable("/views/mainPage", null)).build();
    }
}
```

What I do wrong? And how it possible to fix?

Comment: Did you configure the JSP location as per e.g. http://blog.usul.org/using-jsp-in-a-jersey-jax-rs-restful-application/ ?

Comment: No, i just have a `jboss-web.xml`, but when project was created it showed `Hello.jsp`